# Swagger issue after upgrading framework to .NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

We have a .NET Core web API that was on framework 2.1.  I updated it to .NET Core 3.1, which of course involved some coding changes for compatibility.  Currently I can run it locally from VS and it works fine - I can view the index page with Swagger and all.  But after deploying it to the dev server, it does not load from the server URL (https://[my app].[domain].com/swagger/index.html).  I get a page with this:

[image]

...though there aren't any errors listed in the developer tools.

The out log on the server says this:

> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[0]
> User profile is available. Using 'C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys' as key repository and Windows DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest.
> info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
> Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
> info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
> Hosting environment:
> Production info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0] Content root path:
> E:\Websites[my app] info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQzsM.png)
> Request starting HTTP/2.0 GET https://[my
> app].[domain].com/swagger/index.html
> info:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware[2] Sending file.
> Request path: '/swagger/index.html'. Physical path: 'E:\Websites[my
> app]\wwwroot\swagger\index.html' info:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2] Request finished in
> 21.5241ms 200 text/html info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQzsM.png) Request starting HTTP/2.0
> GET https://[my app].[domain].com/swagger/custom.css info:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware[2] Sending file.
> Request path: '/swagger/custom.css'. Physical path: 'E:\Websites[my
> app]\wwwroot\swagger\custom.css' info:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2] Request finished in
> 1.0042ms 200 text/css info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQzsM.png) Request starting HTTP/2.0
> GET https://[my app].[domain].com/swagger/favicon.ico info:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware[2] Sending file.
> Request path: '/swagger/favicon.ico'. Physical path: 'E:\Websites[my
> app]\wwwroot\swagger\favicon.ico' info:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2] Request finished in
> 1.8643ms 200 image/x-icon info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQzsM.png) Request starting HTTP/2.0
> GET https://[my app].[domain].com/swagger/v3/swagger.json info:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQzsM.png) Request starting HTTP/2.0
> GET https://[my app].[domain].com/swagger/favicon-32x32.png info:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware[2] Sending file.
> Request path: '/swagger/favicon-32x32.png'. Physical path:
> 'E:\Websites[my app]\wwwroot\swagger\favicon-32x32.png' info:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2] Request finished in
> 2.0548ms 200 image/png fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpServer[2]
>
> Connection ID
> "17437937763084179141", Request ID
> "800096c6-0001-f200-b63f-84710c7967bb": An unhandled exception was
> thrown by the application. System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The
> format of the URI could not be determined. at
> System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind)
> at System.Uri..ctor(String uriString) at
> ICE.API.Startup.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.b__5(SwaggerGenOptions
> swagger) in
> D:\ADO\ADOAgent1\Work\206\s[repo][project]\Startup.cs:line
> 119 at
> Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigureNamedOptions`1.Configure(String name, TOptions options) at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory`1.Create(String name) at
> Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsManager`1.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.b__0()....

The packages referenced include (but not limited to):

- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson (3.1.15)
- Swashbuckle.AspNetCore (6.1.5)
- Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Newtonsoft (6.1.5)

This is the contents of Startup.cs, where line 119 (specified in the error above) is `swagger.SwaggerDoc("v3", new OpenApiInfo`:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        string[] allowedOrigins = Configuration.GetSection("appsettings:AllowedPortalUrlCsv").Value.Trim().Split(',');

        services.AddOptions();
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                builder => 
                builder
                    .WithOrigins(allowedOrigins)
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowCredentials()
           );
        });
        services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));
        services.AddSignalR();
        services.AddControllers();

        //Add DB Context:
        services.AddDbContext<ActiveDBContext>(options => options.UseOracle(Configuration["appsettings:connection:activedb"]));

        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

        int timeout; 
        var success = int.TryParse(Configuration["appsettings:sessionidletimeout"], out timeout); 
        timeout = (success ? timeout : 10);

        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(timeout);
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

            //Higher Level Dependency Mappings:
                services.AddTransient<IValidateRequest, ValidateRequest>();
                services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
                services.AddSingleton<IFileProvider>(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IWebHostEnvironment>().ContentRootFileProvider);

            //Add Service Dependencies:
        services.AddScoped<[interface], [service]>();

        services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

        services.Configure<IISOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.AutomaticAuthentication = true;
        });

        services.AddSwaggerGen(swagger =>
        {
            swagger.SwaggerDoc("v3", new OpenApiInfo
            {
                Version = Configuration.GetSection("appsettings:info:version").Value,
                Title = Configuration.GetSection("appsettings:info:title").Value,
                Description = Configuration.GetSection("appsettings:info:description").Value,
                TermsOfService = new Uri(Configuration.GetSection("appsettings:info:termsofservice").Value),
                Contact = new OpenApiContact
                {
                    Name = Configuration.GetSection("appsettings:info:contact:name").Value,
                    Email = Configuration.GetSection("appsettings:info:contact:email").Value,
                    Url = new Uri(Configuration.GetSection("appsettings:info:contact:url").Value),
                },
                License = new OpenApiLicense
                {
                    Name = Configuration.GetSection("appsettings:info:license:name").Value,
                    Url = new Uri(Configuration.GetSection("appsettings:info:license:url").Value),
                }
            });

            var filePath = Path.Combine(PlatformServices.Default.Application.ApplicationBasePath, "[project].xml");

            swagger.IncludeXmlComments(filePath);
            swagger.AddSecurityDefinition("ApiKey", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Description = $"ApiKey for authorization across API (Example: {Configuration.GetSection("appsettings:apikey").Value})",
                Name = "ApiKey",
                In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey
            });
            swagger.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
            {
                {
                    new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                    {
                        Reference = new OpenApiReference
                        {
                            Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                            Id = "ApiKey"
                        }
                    },
                    new string[] { }
                }
            });
        });
        services.AddSwaggerGenNewtonsoftSupport();

        services.AddSingleton(Configuration);
        services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(o =>
        {
            o.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
            o.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
        });        
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        //UseStaticFiles will allow the site to check wwwroot for overriding files to load, such as icons, images, styles, etc...
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        //For .NET Core 3.1, IHostingEnvironment changed to IWebHostEnvironment...but IsDevelopment is in the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting namespace, so that was added up top
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        //Needed for setting if no TNSNames and Local Client is installed:
        OracleConfiguration.OracleDataSources.Add(Configuration.GetSection("appsettings:connection:tnsname").Value, Configuration.GetSection("appsettings:connection:descriptor").Value);
               
        loggerFactory.AddDBLogger(new DBLoggerConfiguration()
        {
            DBConnection = Configuration.GetSection("appsettings:connection:activedb").Value,
            LogLevelAsString = Configuration.GetSection("appsettings:internalloglevel").Value.ToLower(),
            EnableFallBackLogger = true
        });

        //Swagger API Documentation:
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("./swagger/v3/swagger.json", $"{Configuration.GetSection("appsettings:info:title").Value} {Configuration.GetSection("appsettings:info:version").Value}");
        });

        app.UseMiddleware<ApiKeyValidatorsMiddleware>();

        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

        app.UseSession();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapHub<Domain.Helpers.NotifyHub>("/notify");
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

This is the contents of index.html:

```
<!-- HTML for static distribution bundle build -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>[my website]</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700|Source+Code+Pro:300,600|Titillium+Web:400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://unpkg.com/swagger-ui/dist/swagger-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./custom.css">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="./favicon.ico">
    <style>

        html {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical;
            overflow-y: scroll;
        }

        *,
        *:before,
        *:after {
            box-sizing: inherit;
        }

        body {
            margin: 0;
            background: #fafafa;
        }
    </style>
    <link href='/swagger/custom.css' rel='stylesheet' media='screen' type='text/css' />

</head>

<body>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="position:absolute;width:0;height:0">
  <defs>
    <symbol viewBox="0 0 20 20" id="unlocked">
          <path d="M15.8 8H14V5.6C14 2.703 12.665 1 10 1 7.334 1 6 2.703 6 5.6V6h2v-.801C8 3.754 8.797 3 10 3c1.203 0 2 .754 2 2.199V8H4c-.553 0-1 .646-1 1.199V17c0 .549.428 1.139.951 1.307l1.197.387C5.672 18.861 6.55 19 7.1 19h5.8c.549 0 1.428-.139 1.951-.307l1.196-.387c.524-.167.953-.757.953-1.306V9.199C17 8.646 16.352 8 15.8 8z"></path>
    </symbol>

    <symbol viewBox="0 0 20 20" id="locked">
      <path d="M15.8 8H14V5.6C14 2.703 12.665 1 10 1 7.334 1 6 2.703 6 5.6V8H4c-.553 0-1 .646-1 1.199V17c0 .549.428 1.139.951 1.307l1.197.387C5.672 18.861 6.55 19 7.1 19h5.8c.549 0 1.428-.139 1.951-.307l1.196-.387c.524-.167.953-.757.953-1.306V9.199C17 8.646 16.352 8 15.8 8zM12 8H8V5.199C8 3.754 8.797 3 10 3c1.203 0 2 .754 2 2.199V8z"/>
    </symbol>

    <symbol viewBox="0 0 20 20" id="close">
      <path d="M14.348 14.849c-.469.469-1.229.469-1.697 0L10 11.819l-2.651 3.029c-.469.469-1.229.469-1.697 0-.469-.469-.469-1.229 0-1.697l2.758-3.15-2.759-3.152c-.469-.469-.469-1.228 0-1.697.469-.469 1.228-.469 1.697 0L10 8.183l2.651-3.031c.469-.469 1.228-.469 1.697 0 .469.469.469 1.229 0 1.697l-2.758 3.152 2.758 3.15c.469.469.469 1.229 0 1.698z"/>
    </symbol>

    <symbol viewBox="0 0 20 20" id="large-arrow">
      <path d="M13.25 10L6.109 2.58c-.268-.27-.268-.707 0-.979.268-.27.701-.27.969 0l7.83 7.908c.268.271.268.709 0 .979l-7.83 7.908c-.268.271-.701.27-.969 0-.268-.269-.268-.707 0-.979L13.25 10z"/>
    </symbol>

    <symbol viewBox="0 0 20 20" id="large-arrow-down">
      <path d="M17.418 6.109c.272-.268.709-.268.979 0s.271.701 0 .969l-7.908 7.83c-.27.268-.707.268-.979 0l-7.908-7.83c-.27-.268-.27-.701 0-.969.271-.268.709-.268.979 0L10 13.25l7.418-7.141z"/>
    </symbol>


    <symbol viewBox="0 0 24 24" id="jump-to">
      <path d="M19 7v4H5.83l3.58-3.59L8 6l-6 6 6 6 1.41-1.41L5.83 13H21V7z"/>
    </symbol>

    <symbol viewBox="0 0 24 24" id="expand">
      <path d="M10 18h4v-2h-4v2zM3 6v2h18V6H3zm3 7h12v-2H6v2z"/>
    </symbol>

  </defs>
</svg>

<div id="swagger-ui"></div>

<!-- Workaround for https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-editor/issues/1371 -->
<script>
  if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Edge") > -1) {
    console.log("Removing native Edge fetch in favor of swagger-ui's polyfill")
    window.fetch = undefined;
  }
</script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/swagger-ui-dist@3/swagger-ui-bundle.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swagger-ui-dist@3/swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>
  window.onload = function () {
    var configObject = JSON.parse('{"urls":[{"url":"/swagger/v3/swagger.json","name":"[my website] v3"}],"validatorUrl":null}');
    var oauthConfigObject = JSON.parse('{}');

    /*Apply mandatory parameters*/
    configObject.dom_id = "#swagger-ui";
    configObject.presets = [SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis, SwaggerUIStandalonePreset];
    configObject.layout = "StandaloneLayout";

    /*If oauth2RedirectUrl isn't specified, use the built-in default*/
    if (!configObject.hasOwnProperty("oauth2RedirectUrl"))
      configObject.oauth2RedirectUrl = window.location.href.replace("index.html", "oauth2-redirect.html");

    /*Build a system*/
    const ui = SwaggerUIBundle(configObject);

    /*Apply OAuth config*/
    ui.initOAuth(oauthConfigObject);
  }
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

It must have something to do with the contents of `AddSwaggerGen` in Startup.  I tried googling it but couldn't see any particular issues, so I'm not sure what else I need to do.  Note the version that is on .NET Core 2.1 loads swagger in the URL just fine.

Comment: As the error message said, the swagger-ui-bundle.js file load failed, so it causes the SwaggerUIBundle is not defined. Please check the relates package in your application, whether it is exists or not, if not try to copy these files to the server side or re-deploy the application to the server. Besides, you can also add the swagger-ui-bundle.js file using the CDN reference: `<script src="https://unpkg.com/swagger-ui-dist@3/swagger-ui-bundle.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>`.

Comment: @ZhiLv - I tried that. Now what I get when I load the dev URL is still a blank page, but the developer tools error says "The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol."  I'll update the question with the changes I'd made to try and fix that but still isn't working.

Comment: Try to change the `<meta charset="UTF-8">` to `<meta charset="utf-8" />` or `<meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/> <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding"/>`.

Comment: OK, I tried that.  I still get the same error in the browser.  I got the out log file and the error there says the issue is something with the swagger gen in Startup.cs.  I'm going to change my question to contain the current contents.  Thank you!